# Python infinity threading loop without duplicate or interrupt thread task

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this code to create a infinity threading loop without duplicate or interrupt thread task.

```
import threading
import time
thread = None

def loopMyTask():
    global thread
    if thread is not None and thread.isAlive():
        thread.cancel()
        thread.join()
            
    thread = threading.Timer(6.0, loopMyTask)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    myTask()

def myTask():
    # simulate a task
    for i in range(14) :
        print(str(i))
        time.sleep(1)

while True:
    loopMyTask()
```

Apparently it's working, but it returns an alert

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to do, but only the main thread does some work here:

1. you call `loopMyTask()`
2. it sets a timer to start a new thread calling itself in 6s
3. it calls `myTask`, which prints 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...
4. the timer triggers a call to `loopmytask()` in a new thread.
5. the new thread finds that the global variable `thread` is set (and the thread is alive) so it calls `cancel`. That does nothing: it is meant to cancel the timer, but it already has finished. Indeed, this part of the code is running because the time has arrived
6. the new thread calls `thread.join()`, which would cause a deadlock since it would be waiting for itself to finish. Fortunately, the `threading` module prevents this kind of deadlocks and raises a `RuntimeError`. The thread dies.
7. the main thread resumes its execution of `myTask`, printing 6, 7, 8...
8. once it finishes, the loop goes again to step 1. The `thread.join()` call does not trigger an error this time, but everything repeats again.

So, you would get the same results (aside from the error) if you just call `myTask()` in a loop